# innerText is undefined in Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, scope

I've made code to query a document for matching strings and make a URL from the strings obtained. It looks through the tag elements looking for matches, makes the URL string, then it appends the link to the designated `parentNode` object.  This code works fine in plain javascript, but it breaks when I stick it in Greasemonkey.  I can't figure out why.

Here is a fully working version when I stick it in the chrome console:

```
//loop  through elements by classname and find string matches
regexQueryEmail = "(AccountEmailAddress\\s)(.+?)(\\n)"
regexQueryContact = "(Contact with ID: )(.+?)(\\D)"

var Tags = document.getElementsByClassName('msg-body-div')
for (i = 0; i < Tags.length; i++) {
    matchEmail = Tags[i].innerText.match(regexQueryEmail)
    matchContact = Tags[i].innerText.match(regexQueryContact)
    if (matchEmail != null) {
        var emailString = matchEmail[2]
        var placeHolder = Tags[i]
    }
    if (matchContact != null) {
        var idString = matchContact[2]
    }
}

var urlFirst = "https://cscentral.foo.com/gp/stores/www.foo.com/gp/communications/manager/main/191- 4559276-8054240?ie=UTF8&customerEmailAddress="
var urlSecond = "%3E&initialCommId="
var cscURL = urlFirst + emailString + urlSecond + idString

var cscLink = document.createElement('a')
cscLink.innerText = 'Communication History'
cscLink.href = cscURL
placeHolder.parentNode.appendChild(cscLink)
```

When I stick it in Greasemonkey, it gives me this error from the Greasemonkey "Edit" screen:

```
/*
    Exception: Tags[i].innerText is undefined
    @Scratchpad:18
*/
```

---

It has also told me that "placeHolder" is undefined, but I am unable to replicate this right now. I have a feeling that it has something to do with how the variables are scoped.  I've added "var Tags;" and "var placeHolder;" to the top of the script and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox uses the `element.textContent` property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.textContent

The variable `placeholder` in never declared in the scope you try to use it in. Instead it's declared somewhere in your `for` loop. Make sure you declare it within the same scope.

E.g.

```
var Tags = document.getElementsByClassName('msg-body-div')

var placeholder; // declare in same scope

for (var i = 0; i < Tags.length; i++) {

    // lookup the tag once
    var tag = Tags[i];

    // get the text only once
    var text = tag.textContent;

    matchEmail = text.match(regexQueryEmail)
    matchContact = text.match(regexQueryContact)

    if (matchEmail != null) {
        var emailString = matchEmail[2]

        placeHolder = tag // deleted var statement
    }
    if (matchContact != null) {
        var idString = matchContact[2]
    }
}

...

// now you can use it.

if (placeHolder) {
    placeHolder.parentNode.appendChild(cscLink);
}
```